# Using line thickness as a loop variable in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

Here is a **very** simple code that *mysteriously* does not work; a simple `pgf` loop where the first variable is the *y-coordinate* and the second variable is the line *thickness*. LaTeX rejects the thickness saying "`I do not know the key '/tikz/ thin`"

My code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.3cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \path (0,0) coordinate (current); %start point  
        \foreach \ylabel / \labelthickness in {1 / thin , 2 / thick , -4 / semithick }
        { 
            \draw [\labelthickness] (current) -- +(1,\ylabel) coordinate (current) ;
        } 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please give some explanation why my code does not work, I am clueless.

Comment: It doesn't like the space. Try `1/thin,2/thick...`.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks! Wow, that's crazy, the expression is so space sensitive! Even if I write `{1/thin,2/thick,-4/semithick }` it would complain about the space behind `semithick`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TikZ is interpreting the spaces as part of the keys which is why it doesn't recognise `/tikz/ thin`. Fortunately, it knows all about `/tikz/thin`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0) coordinate (current); %start point
  \foreach \ylabel / \labelthickness in {1/thin,2/thick,-4/semithick}
  {
    \draw [\labelthickness] (current) -- +(1,\ylabel) coordinate (current) ;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: variable thickness loop]